# Using AWS Cloudwatch Agent to Monitor Openstack IaaS cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-cloudwatch, openstack, monitor

Please, I do want to know if it is possible to monitor instances in openstack using AWS Cloudwatch agent or using any other AWS resource. If not possible, what will be my best tool(s) to go for as we currently have instances running in openstack but don't have visibility on how they are performing.
Thank you